# C# : Removing Columns from Datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

Suppose I have two tables

Table 1 with following columns (Dots to represent columns in between)

```
id int
name varchar
.
.
.
.
LastChanged datetime
```

Table 2 with following columns

```
id int
Address varchar
.
.
.
.
LastChanged datetime
```

I executed a query like below in C# and stored the result in a `Datatable`.

```
select * from table1 t1
inner join  table2 t2
on t1.id=t2.id
```

Now I don't want the column `LastChanged`  in the result.

`LastChanged` column is present in both tables. Since `Datatable` doesn't allow duplicate column names, one of the `LastChanged` column in result is renamed to `LastChanged1`

So when I try to remove the column using

```
if (table.Columns.Contains("LastChanged"))
                table.Columns.Remove("LastChanged");
```

Only one `LastChanged` is removed. The other one remains.

One solution is to eliminate `LastChanged` in the query itself
by specifying the required columns.
But it makes query long since almost all columns except `LastChanged` is needed in result.

Is there a solution in C#?

Comment: Specifying the columns list in the query is the correct solution. It's better than selecting columns you don't need....

Comment: Any best practice I have heard of requires explicit column specification no matter how long the list.  It is widely recommended to not use * in production code.

Comment: Yeah.. I agree.. :) Right now I am using that.

Comment: Why are you using a DataTable in the first place?

Comment: @mason I am displaying result in datagridview. datatable is its source

Comment: Why not use strongly typed objects and bind to that instead? Create classes that represent your data. The result will be less memory usage, strongly typed properties, better designer experience. DataTable is a leaky abstraction and should be avoided for the most part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read carefully: [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

However, to answer the question, you could do this LINQ approach:

```
string colName = "LastChanged";
var lastChangedColumnList = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
  .Where(c => c.ColumnName.StartsWith(colName) && c.ColumnName.Substring(colName.Length).All(char.IsDigit))
  .ToList();

foreach(DataColumn col in lastChangedColumnList)
    table.Columns.Remove(col);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to achieve this

```
var lst = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
     .Where(x => x.ColumnName.StartsWith("LastChanged"))
     .ToList();


foreach(DataColumn col in lst){
      table.Columns.Remove(col);}
```

Comment: So you remove also `NotLastChangedButSomethingElse`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, i changed it to StartsWith, but i used contains because the OP used it

Comment: But the pattern a DataTable uses to create column-names which are already contained is to append `1`, `2`,`3`....`12345`. So the duplicate number is appended. OP doesnt want to remove similar named columns but duplicate columns.

Comment: @Yahfoufi Actually I hadn't noticed the case of duplicate columns while writing the code. My mistake. Thank you both :)